# AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access an outlook mailbox through Azure app and I am running into this problem. I've used the steps from this blog:

https://medium.com/@manojkumardhakad/python-read-and-send-outlook-mail-using-oauth2-token-and-graph-api-53de606ecfa1

...and it worked for me when I created the secret for the first time.
However, after changing the secret as per our password rotation policy, I'm not able to regenerate the auth token using the auth code that I got in the first step from the browser.

In the second step of redeeming the auth code for an auth token, I keep getting  the error message "AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app XXX". I have tried this multiple new secrets, with and without url encoding.

I'm fully sure that I'm not using the secret ID, but the secret value. I've also made sure the client_Id and Tenant_ID and all other parameters are correct and are those that worked for me the first time.

I've tried the steps from:

https://medium.com/@manojkumardhakad/python-read-and-send-outlook-mail-using-oauth2-token-and-graph-api-53de606ecfa1

...and it worked for me when I created the secret for the first time.

Comment: is it possible for you to confirm if the client secret you used in your app is already turned to be the new secret when your app is running? If the secret already become the new secret you created in Azure AD, could you please wait for 10 minutes and test again? just like what you said, your code should work all the time, so it's weird...